# How to migrate from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, migration

I have this scenario:

**Old Server** -> SQL Server 2005 with the current Database

**New Server** -> SQL Server 2012 no database created.

I want to migrate the old database to the new one.

I've tried to create a backup from the Management Studio 2005 and restore in the 2012. Failed.

I've connected from the 2012 server using Management Studio 2012 to the old server and create the backup. Then restored in the new one. Failed.
The error said that the versions are incompatibles (tried to restored a version from 8.0 to 11.0)

Then, I tried to use the **Copy database Wizard**. But a error message shows up:
***The destination server can not be an instance of SQL Server 2005 Express or higher .***

So, how it is supposed to do the backup?

I'm getting the scripts in sql files as last resort...

PS: I've check this thread, I need to migrate to 2008 and then 2012?
[How to migrate a database from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 as is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368451/how-to-migrate-a-database-from-sql-server-2005-to-2008-as-is)

Comment: are you using SQL server express anywhere in here?  You have not mentioned this, but your error message states otherwise.

Comment: both are free version, so I suppose that they are both express (not very sure)

Comment: This sounds like a question to the dba site, since this is not programming related. Also, if something fails, you really should include the error message.

Comment: if you are a Admin the 2 way 1) restore the DB. 2) attach mdf and ldf file. it will automatically upgrade

Answer (score 0):

When I have performed a SQL Server migration in the past I have normally performed a SQL Backup, copy to the new server and then restore, I see in your question that you got an error, update the question with the error and perhaps we can be more specific about what you need to do to make it succeed.

I have also performed a migration by detaching the database from the old server, copying the data and log files to the new server and attaching the databases.  This is the method I tend to go with.

The SQL you would use to attach the MDF/LDF files is as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks 
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf'), 
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf') 
    FOR ATTACH;
```

You can refer to the documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms190209(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: I've added the error. It's about versions. (The error is in spanish, I've traslated to english)

Comment: Can you upgrade the database version from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005?  This might allow you to perform the backup and restore.  Also have you tried detaching and attaching the database?

Answer (score 0):

Please apply latest service pack SP4 on 2005 databases after this take a full backup of 2005 databases and restore it on 2012. I hope, it will work.